# Android, HttpURLConnection, PUT and Authenticator

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, put, authenticator

```
url = new URL(UPLOAD_URL);

urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/json");
urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(responseJSONArray.toString(2).getBytes("UTF8").length);
urlConnection.setDoInput(false);
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(this.CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
urlConnection.connect();
OutputStream output = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
output.write(responseJSONArray.toString(2).getBytes("UTF8"));
output.close();
```

I've also already earlier set the Authenticator with:

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator()
{
 @Override
  protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
  {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(loginNameString, passwordString.toCharArray());
  }
});
```

I supply correct login details, but the server responds with a `401` code. (A similar GET-request works though.) On top of which, the method `getPasswordAuthentication()` is not being called in the process of connecting and writing to the stream. (I know this because I put in `Log.v("app", "password here")`.)

Why is that?

Comment: have you solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not able to answer to why using Authenticator does not work, but I usually use this approach:

```
    String webPage = "http://192.168.1.1";
    String name = "admin";
    String password = "admin";

    String authString = name + ":" + password;
    byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
    String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);

    URL url = new URL(webPage);
    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
    InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
```

Try it. Using basic auth should be enough.

Comment: PUT it's just a type of request. For web request I usually use basic auth. Is it not working for you?

Comment: No, not yet. We can't tell what the problem is - we'll keep trying!